# Unreal Engine 4: Super::Tick ( DeltaTime )

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I'm new to Unreal Engine 4 and thought the docs posted on their website would be a good place to start. However, I'm struggling with some things concerning the coding part (I have a pretty decent C++ knowledge). Here is the code extract I'm having some trouble with:

```
void AFloatingActor::Tick( float DeltaTime )
{
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

    FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();
    float DeltaHeight = (FMath::Sin(RunningTime + DeltaTime) - FMath::Sin(RunningTime));
    NewLocation.Z += DeltaHeight * 20.0f;       //Scale our height by a factor of 20
    RunningTime += DeltaTime;
    SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
}
```

I do not get how this works. I pretty much get the statements and all but I don't get how it works. So tick basically is a function called each tick (frame) and any other statements added are to edit the logic of the actor each frame. How does this work? Shouldn't the first statement "Super::Tick ( DeltaTime );" cause an endless recursion as there is no base (stopping) case?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you so much

Comment: Why would it be endless recursion? It's not calling itself, so it's not recursive at all. What is `Super`?

Comment: `Super::Tick` simply calls the tick in the parent class. Instead of remembering what each classes parent is called, UE4 defines `Super` so the virtual functions of the derived classes can easily call the parent version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no recursion here - it's calling `Super::Tick`, not itself.

`Super` is most likely a typedef of the base class, intended so that you can call its functions without having to remember its actual name in all situations.

So `Super::Tick(DeltaTime);` calls the `Tick` function in the base class (and passes it `DeltaTime` as an argument). This is useful if you override a function, but still want the "normal" stuff to happen as well as the stuff you wrote in your override.